# NULL Values on query condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to compare null values using not in and exists but I found some diferences
Why the latest query returns null? is it related to a db parameter?

```
--SET ANSI_NULLS On

CREATE TABLE #Tmp (id INT)
CREATE TABLE #Tmp1 (id INT)

INSERT INTO #Tmp(id) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #Tmp(id) VALUES (null)


INSERT INTO #Tmp1(id) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #Tmp1(id) VALUES (null)

SELECT id FROM #Tmp WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM #tmp1)

SELECT id FROM #Tmp WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #Tmp1 WHERE #Tmp1.id = #Tmp.id)

SELECT id FROM #Tmp WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM #tmp1)

SELECT id FROM #Tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #Tmp1 WHERE #Tmp1.id = #Tmp.id)

DROP TABLE #Tmp
DROP TABLE #Tmp1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server,  remember that NULL does not return an equality check of TRUE with anything (unless you are playing with ANSI_NULLS):

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE 1=NULL

SELECT 1
WHERE NULL = NULL
```

It only returns True when you use IS/IS NOT

```
SELECT 1
WHERE NULL IS NULL
```

For your last query, the only record that satisfies that requirement in the WHERE clause is your NULL row. The equivalent is:

```
SELECT id FROM #Tmp 
WHERE id IS NULL
```

To solve your issue, throw a second clause on there:

```
SELECT id FROM #Tmp 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 
FROM #Tmp1 
WHERE #Tmp1.id = #Tmp.id OR #Tmp.id IS NULL
)
```

Comment: does not depends on the ANSI_NULLS ? because I would like to use not exists

Comment: @carlosm You're right. I missed that commented out part. If ANSI_NULLs is getting turned on and off, that will change output. If it is OFF, NULL=NULL is true. But that gets dicey quick. I would recommend against it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple:

```
id IN (1, NULL)
<=>
id = 1 OR id = NULL
```

And [negation of alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
id NOT IN (1, NULL)
<=>
id != 1 AND id != NULL -- yields NULL
```

---

Summary:

If you want to use `NOT IN` make sure your list does not contain `NULL`.

```
SELECT id FROM #Tmp WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM #tmp1 WHERE id IS NOT NULL)

SELECT id FROM #Tmp WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT COALESCE(id,-1) FROM #tmp1)
```